# linked list add function does not store data

Tags: c

I tried to add book from the line and store it in the linked list. However, when I tried to do so, it keeps reading from the file.

I added a print statement before the statement `if (current == NULL)`, and it returns as an empty linked list.

After reading the file, I can get the correct result, but as soon as it popped out of the if loop, the current node became empty again.

Here is the code:

```
typedef struct _Book
{
    int ISBN;
    char Title[20];
    char Author[20];
    char Description[40];
    int CopiesAtCSU;


    struct _Book *next;
} Book;

int add(Book **listHead,int ISBN,char *Title,char *Author, int CopiesAtCsu, char *description,  int sortIndx){
    current = listHead; 
    prev = null; 
    newNode = null;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Book));
    newNode->ISBN = ISBN;
    //newNode->Title = Title;
    strcpy(newNode->Title, Title);
    //newNode->Author = Author;
    strcpy(newNode->Author, Author);
    newNode->CopiesAtCSU = CopiesAtCsu;
    //newNode->Description = description;
    strcpy(newNode->Description, description);
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (*listHead == NULL){
    current = newNode;
    printf("\n check current in the loop: \n");
    displayBookList(current);
    listHead = current;
    printf("\n ");
    }
}
```

display is a method just print all the items in the linked list.

Comment: What is Book? What is current? What are a lot of other variables? Please give us more information if you want to be helped.

Comment: Could you post a [MCVE](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? As it stands, it is hard to tell what is your bug. By MCVE I mean, what is `displayBookList()`, `current`, `prev`, and `newNode`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a dereference when you assign to list head.

```
if (*listHead == NULL){
    current = newNode;
    printf("\n check current in the loop: \n");
    displayBookList(current);
    *listHead = current;   // <------- ERROR: This needs to be dereferenced. In your code you do listhead=current without the dereference.
    printf("\n ");
}
```

However, in your question you say after the if statement, **current** is showing as empty. This is not related to the bug above. Could you show your `displayBookList()` method? I'm pretty sure your problem is with dereferencing and levels of indirection: even in your first line, shouldn't you be doing `current = *listhead` as opposed to `current = listhead`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit incomplete. It's not clear if you want to insert at the front of the list or at the end.

To insert at the front, `newNode->next` must be set to `*listHead`.

To insert at the end, `newNode->next` must be set to `NULL`. You have to find the pointer to the last node in the existing list, so you need a `for` loop.

I've provided both ways:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _Book {
    int ISBN;
    char Title[20];
    char Author[20];
    char Description[40];
    int CopiesAtCSU;

    struct _Book *next;
} Book;

void
add_to_front(Book **listHead,int ISBN,char *Title,char *Author,int CopiesAtCsu,
    char *description, int sortIndx)
{
    Book *newNode;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Book));

    newNode->ISBN = ISBN;
    strcpy(newNode->Title, Title);
    strcpy(newNode->Author, Author);
    newNode->CopiesAtCSU = CopiesAtCsu;
    strcpy(newNode->Description, description);

    newNode->next = *listHead;
    *listHead = newNode;
}

void
add_to_back(Book **listHead,int ISBN,char *Title,char *Author,int CopiesAtCsu,
    char *description, int sortIndx)
{
    Book *newNode;
    Book *cur;
    Book *prev;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Book));

    newNode->ISBN = ISBN;
    strcpy(newNode->Title, Title);
    strcpy(newNode->Author, Author);
    newNode->CopiesAtCSU = CopiesAtCsu;
    strcpy(newNode->Description, description);

    prev = NULL;
    for (cur = *listHead;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        prev = cur;

    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = newNode;
    else
        *listHead = newNode;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! It is my belief that it is sometimes easier to see things in code rather than just an explanation and it can be a better teacher. If you really like it, you can upvote and accept the answer. Happy Programming!